# Integrated Terminal Window in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, terminal

I recently started using NetBeans, but there is a missing feature which keeps me from switching completely to NetBeans. I use the Terminal all the time and it is a pain to switch from the NetBeans window to the Terminal one.

Is there a way to have a terminal window embedded into the NetBeans IDE (most Linux editors have this capability)?

Answer (score 81):

A bit late answer. Netbeans 7.4 has an inbuilt support for terminal emulator. All you need is to go to `Window->IDE Tools->Terminal`.

Comment: This should be accepeted

Comment: I was getting an error, "unable to start pty process", which I resolved by updating cygwin to the latest version. Cygwin can be updated be rerunning the installer.

Comment: @DavidS i have update cygwin but i cant use the terminal did you have same problem?it just turns white for a moment then return to original state the gray one where you cant type anything

Answer (score 16):

Using **NetBeans 8.0.2**, this option can be found by going to `Window->IDE Tools->Terminal` in the menu.

Comment: Note that, (on Windows), this options requires cygwin.

Comment: It requries cygwin which is heavy and everyone may not have. They should consider supporting `git bash` which is a lighter version and mostly all developers have it.

Answer (score 12):

have you seen this?
http://wiki.netbeans.org/TerminalEmulator

or this

http://wiki.netbeans.org/AJourneyThroughTheVirtualTerminal

I am not really seeing that much out there. I wonder how hard it would be to take the plugin from jEdit and integrate it into netbeans.